# Property does not exist on type union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

I've searched trough the stackoverflow questions but didn't find the needed answer in my case.
**I have**

```
interface FruitBox {
  name: string
  desc: {
   'orange': number;
   'banana': number;
  }
}

interface IceBox {
  name: string
}

interface Vegabox {
  name: string
  desc: {
   'tomato': number;
   'potato': number;
  }
}

type UnionBox = FruitBox | Vegabox | IceBox;
```

**What I'm trying to implement**

```
type Ship = Record<string, (description: UnionBox['desc'] | UnionBox['name']) => void>;
```

I'm trying to assign a `description` property to a type of `UnionBox['desc']` and if `desc` parameter doesn't exist, then assign it to the `UnionBox['name']`

Receiving next error:
`Property 'desc' does not exist on type 'UnionBox'`

Would be glad for any help or hint

*ps. I understand that there must be some weird algorithm, Just not sure in which way to look*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208056/union-types-not-being-recognised-in-react/69208481#69208481). The case is very similar.

When TypeScript resolves union type it allows you to use [best common type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type). I mean the type which is common for all union elements. Because this option is the safest one.

Let's inspect your union:

```js
interface FruitBox {
  name: string
  desc: {
   'orange': number;
   'banana': number;
  }
}

interface IceBox {
  name: string
}

interface Vegabox {
  name: string
  desc: {
   'tomato': number;
   'potato': number;
  }
}

type UnionBox = FruitBox | Vegabox | IceBox;

type AllowedKeys = keyof UnionBox // name
```

As you might have noticed (`AllowedKeys`) you are only allowed to use `name` property from the `UnionBox`. Why ? Because `name` exists in each union.

In order to handle it, you might want to use `StrictUnion` helper.

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = 
    T extends any 
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>
```

Full code:

```js
interface FruitBox {
    name: string
    desc: {
        'orange': number;
        'banana': number;
    }
}

interface IceBox {
    name: string
}

interface Vegabox {
    name: string
    desc: {
        'tomato': number;
        'potato': number;
    }
}

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type UnionBox = StrictUnion<FruitBox | Vegabox | IceBox>;

type AllowedKeys = keyof UnionBox // name


type Ship = Record<string, (description: UnionBox['desc'] | UnionBox['name']) => void>; // ok


const record: Ship = {
    foo: (elem) => { }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DAIQPYAeyA3gFDIXIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDm5lAJhEwozKVhyAOR4ocEOwijGIDDQBG0ANxcRYpVJ1yqilVHXCAvqTOlQkWIhQBJJPiJDK1OoxZtp50pfDR4JGQANQh2OCVCEg0qWgZmVg4Y3n5BGOFRMDwaOCy9BWU1dMpRAAc8MFy8fIMi0x9SMABPUpQAVRBgPBAAaQgmpgAeABUAPmQAXmRh5AgCSBBuJmnkAH5kAGt%20vBgV%20QgANyLm1uQAZUSEMA6ukAAJCAAbVqgRgBppgEFHx-GJmJmcwWS2QUiaMXWMwAZMgAApwKBgYBwR6DABKEAQEm4gwAogQEI8MLxBjdun0BiNvr8PlsmjtpqMPiBDtBRuN9kcjL4TigLmwrmSQCM-udLtdOt0Hs9oO9GTyWu1JSAnJMxQKJbdBugsLgogAfEJhCIG5AOCBOUbqRqK5DUvAAdwg3ApyymdIZQtVAHpvbE6L4baczgALYClNUYrFQHGeDgfAAUKQQbFKSO6jC9hAA2qJk6IALrIQ1Zgi5tyyAsASkm4wOeGA3CtgaxIBYyCgmOxjFD4bVLgoMDweEYCaeEBoNYm42IyDMZiAA)

Answer (score 0):

`UnionBox` from your example can be one of the types - `FruitBox`, `Vegabox`, or `IceBox`. `IceBox` is the one that makes Typescript unhappy - it doesn't contain a property `desc`. Imagine having an object of type `IceBox`, then passing it to a function, which takes `UnionBox` as a parameter and then uses the property `desc` - it would access a non-existing one.

> I'm trying to assign a description property to a type of UnionBox['desc'] and if desc parameter doesn't exist, then assign it to the UnionBox['name']

I'm not sure how you expect it to work, since the description is simply typed as either string or string in your example - | operator will simply create a union. But I guess you could simply accept `unionBox: UnionBox` as a parameter, and add a logic inside which would have `unionBox.desc ?? unionBox.name` to get `name` if `desc` does not exist.

Comment: I will make an example  more complex. They are different types.
That's the part of my logic, I don't want to pass whole object trough the function args, just one property named 'desk' or 'name'

Comment: made an example more complex